No se muestra el contenido inicial de una shiny app con módulos de bienvenida y login
Estoy intentando desarrollar una shiny app usando shinydashboard, y estructurándola con módulos. Por ahora solo tengo dos módulos: uno de login y uno de bienvenida. La idea es que luego de un login exitoso se muestre el mensaje de bienvenida. Pero por algún motivo eso no está pasando: luego de que el usuario hace el login, solo se muestra el cuerpo del dashboard vacío. ¿dónde está mi error?
app.R:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

source("modules/login_module.R", encoding = "UTF-8")
source("modules/welcome_module.R", encoding = "UTF-8")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Ejemplo App con Login"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "sidebarMenu", 
      menuItem("Bienvenida", tabName = "welcome", icon = icon("home"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),     
    uiOutput("loginUI"),     
    uiOutput("mainUI")       
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  user_base <- data.frame(
    user = c("user1", "user2"),
    password = c("pass1", "pass2"),
    name = c("User One", "User Two"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  
  user <- callModule(loginServer, "loginModule", credentials = user_base)
  
  output$loginUI <- renderUI({
    if (!user$login) {
      loginUI("loginModule")
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    if (user$login) {
      output$mainUI <- renderUI({
        tabItems(
          tabItem(tabName = "welcome", welcomeUI("welcomeModule", user$name))
        )
      })
      
      hide("loginUI")
      show("sidebarMenu")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)



login_module.r:
# UI del login
loginUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(ns("userName"), "Nombre de usuario"),
    passwordInput(ns("passwd"), "Contraseña"),
    actionButton(ns("login"), "Acceder"),
    textOutput(ns("errorMsg"))
  )
}

# server del login
loginServer <- function(input, output, session, credentials) {
  user <- reactiveValues(login = FALSE, name = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$login, {
    Username <- input$userName
    Password <- input$passwd
    
    if (Username %in% credentials$user) {
      if (Password == credentials$password[credentials$user == Username]) {
        user$login <- TRUE
        user$name <- credentials$name[credentials$user == Username]
      } else {
        output$errorMsg <- renderText("Contraseña incorrecta")
      }
    } else {
      output$errorMsg <- renderText("Usuario no encontrado")
    }
  })
  
  return(user)
}


welcome_module.R:
welcomeUI <- function(id, name) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$div(
    tags$h2(paste("¡Bienvenido,", name, "!")),
    tags$p("Has iniciado sesión correctamente.")
  )
}

